# PowerBI - Select last non-blank value of a Measure based on most recent Date

Tags: powerbi, dax

I have the following table in PowerBI :

```
FullDate              Visits     Orders    ConversionRate
01/02/2020 00:00:00    100         20           0,20
01/02/2020 01:00:00    550         78           0,14
01/02/2020 02:00:00    652         60           0,09
01/02/2020 03:00:00     0           0           0,00
01/02/2020 04:00:00     0           0           0,00
01/02/2020 05:00:00     0           0           0,00
```

ConversionRate is a measure :

```
ConversionRate = DIVIDE(SUM(Table[Orders]),SUM(Table[Visits]))
```

I need to get the value of  trying to display in a card the latest non-blank value of ConversionRate based on the date.

I tried this but it returned empty in all the fields :

```
LastValue = 
CALCULATE(
    DIVIDE(SUM([Orders]),SUM([Visits])),
    FILTER(Table, Table[FullDate] = MAX( Table[FullDate] ) && Table[Visits] <> 0 )
)
```

This returned the same value as ConversionRate for each row.

```
FullDate              Visits     Orders    ConversionRate   LastValue
01/02/2020 00:00:00    100         20           0,20          0,20
01/02/2020 01:00:00    550         78           0,14          0,14
01/02/2020 02:00:00    652         60           0,09          0,09
01/02/2020 03:00:00     0           0           0,00          0,00
01/02/2020 04:00:00     0           0           0,00          0,00
01/02/2020 05:00:00     0           0           0,00          0,00
```

What I want is :

```
FullDate              Visits     Orders    ConversionRate   LastValue
01/02/2020 00:00:00    100         20           0,20          0,09
01/02/2020 01:00:00    550         78           0,14          0,09
01/02/2020 02:00:00    652         60           0,09          0,09
01/02/2020 03:00:00     0           0           0,00          0,00
01/02/2020 04:00:00     0           0           0,00          0,00
01/02/2020 05:00:00     0           0           0,00          0,00
```

I am sure I am missing something but I am new to DAX.. Any help would be appreciated

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You want to capture your 'max' date before you begin the iteration over 'Table' in the Filter function.   Doing the calculation to discover the max date and assigning it to a variable gets this done.

Then you use your variable in the filter function, and you get the proper result.  An unwanted side effect is that the .09 is calculated in every row, so you have check that Visit column a second time and return a blank if its value is zero.

```
LastConversion = 
VAR maxDate =
    CALCULATE (
        MAX ( 'Table'[FullDate] ),
        FILTER ( ALL ( 'Table' ), 'Table'[Visits] <> 0 )
    )
RETURN
    IF (
        SUM ( 'Table'[Visits] ) = 0,
        BLANK (),
        CALCULATE (
            DIVIDE ( SUM ( [Orders] ), SUM ( [Visits] ) ),
            FILTER ( ALL('Table'), 'Table'[FullDate] = maxDate )
        )
    )
```

[image]